# Javascript / p5.js variable issues

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using p5.js and made a constructor function for a small object.
When I try to update a list of these objects everything starts to affect other objects in a very strange way. Why does it behave like that?

Here is a simplified version of my sketch:

```
var pellets = [],
    cells = []

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 300)
    // ...

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var pos = createVector(random(width), random(height))
        var col = color("#ff0000")
        cells.push(new Bot(pos, col, pelletMiddle))
    }

    // ...
}

function draw() {
    for (var i in pellets) {
        cells[i].update()
        cells[i].draw()
    }
}
```

And here is the constructor function:

```
function Bot(position, col, mass) {
    //private:
    position = position.copy()
    var velocity = createVector()
    var acceleration = createVector()

    //public:
    this.nearby = []
    this.draw = function () {
        fill(col)
        ellipse(position.x, position.y, mass)
    }

    this.getPosition = function () {
        return position.copy()
    }

    this.getDistance = function (vector) {
        return position.dist(vector)
    }

    this.update = function () {
        position.add(velocity)
        velocity.add(acceleration).limit(5)

        var pos = createVector(),
            dist = Infinity
        for (var i in pellets) {
            var lpos = pellets[i].getPosition()
            if (this.getDistance(lpos) < dist) {
                dist = this.getDistance(lpos)
                pos = lpos
            }
        }
        acceleration = pos.sub(position).limit(random(0.5))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific than saying the objects affect each other? What exactly does this code do? Also, where are the `position`, `velocity`, and `acceleration` functions defined?

Comment: Well I get the position from the arguments, all the variables are p5.Vectors (see [p5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createVector)). The objects start to shake and never get to the targets, even when I make sure that the acceleration doesn't change. It seems like the acceleration from every single Bot is applied to every other Bot).

Comment: Can you please post a link to your code running in a JSFiddle or a CodePen?

Comment: [Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWrxGW) is the requested codepen. The player normally shouldn't shake like this. (You can see how it should behave normally when you set c.botAmount to 0

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really see a difference in behavior when I set `botAmount` to `0`. You're going to have much better luck if you post a [mcve] that clearly shows the problem instead of your entire project.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering around a couple of hours I found the issue...
I had a missing `var` before `velocity` and `acceleration`.

So the `velocity` and `acceleration` were just global variables.